# Twilio Media size exceeds Mobile operate Limit

Tags: php, api, twilio

I'm currently using Twilio to build a messaging platform for my school, however when I try and send video, it display's *"Media exceeds mobile operator size limit"*. Does anyone know how to fix this? Or atleast increase the size of the limit?

Comment: Are you trying to send video via MMS?

Comment: Yes I am, my goal is to send a 3 minute video.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [size limit for a piece of media sent over MMS by Twilio is 5MB](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/media). That is the maximum size that the mobile operators will accept (although that differs among operators. When sending images, Twilio is able to do some resizing to fit within the operator restraints, but for any other media, including video, it will be attempted at the size you supply it at.

In order to send your 3 minute video you should resize and compress it as much as you can to get it beneath that 5MB limit. The limit cannot be lifted.

Comment: Hi @philnash, is there any way to bypass image resizing when using Twilio? We're trying to send 1.7MB Gif files but they keep getting resized and become unreadable .

Comment: While operators will accept up to 5MB files, when they are images they can resize the images themselves. This is not under Twilio's control as it is the carrier's affecting the images. Could you consider turning your gif into a video file? It would likely be smaller and would not be resized.

Comment: Thanks!
After much testing, it seems that AT&T is the problem, they won't let any image > than 500KB without resizing it...

Comment: Sorry there's nothing we can do about it! Hope you can find a way around this. I've used [this gif optimizer](https://ezgif.com/optimize) which has a bunch of options, to make gifs smaller before, if that would help.

Comment: Thanks @philnash, we're using [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) to generate our gif files and then [GifSicle](https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle) and [Lossygif](https://kornel.ski/lossygif) to compress them. Thanks again, not Twilio's fault, AT&T sucks...

Comment: Have you tried just sending a video instead of a gif?

Comment: Yes, that works too but we really want the "autoplay" function of the gif

Comment: Ah, fair enough.